# How to have a structured reference respond to filters on a table?

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have a table in Excel with multiple columns. One of the columns is an index column with an arbitrary number (1,2,3..).
At the moment I have a pivot table where the rows of the pivot table are in sync with the rows of the source table, even when filters/sorts are applied.

I am using a structured reference to calculate the sum of a column in the source table:
`=SUM(TABLE[ColumnName])`
But this number remains constant even when filters are applied to TABLE.

How can I make this structured reference responsive to filters applied to TABLE?

Comment: Why can't you use simply `=SUBTOTAL(9,TABLE[ColumnName])`?

Comment: @JosWoolley that works perfectly, thank you very much! Can you please submit that as an answer so that I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `SUM`, use `SUBTOTAL`:

`=SUBTOTAL(9,TABLE[ColumnName])`

Comment: Do you have any idea how I could achieve a similar effect with a Pivot Table instead of a regular table?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Pivot Table aggregations always respond to filtering/slicing of the fields in that Pivot Table.

Comment: @JosWooley My pivot table responds to the filtering of the source table by hiding the appropriate rows, but this is not affecting the totals, including when I use Subtotal(109, ...)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A pivot table should not in any way respond to the hiding of rows within its source table (unless by pure coincidence the Pivot Table happens to reside within the same rows as the table). But the aggregations within a Pivot Table will respond to filtering of the Pivot Table. If that's not what you want then I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The pivot table does reside in the same rows as the source table, but it is not coincidence. As I mentioned in the OP, I have an index column which is how I have managed to get them to sync. I have done this because I am using power pivot, the source table is for manual data entry and then PowerPivot does a series of calculated columns in the data model via table relationships (as opposed to VLOOKUPs).
The Pivot Table has been a means for me to bring back the related calculated data from the model into the main sheet, hence why I want it to sort alongside the source table.

Comment: Your set-up sounds suspect. I have never come across a case in which it is necessary to synchronize the rows of a Pivot Table with those of its source data table. Have you considered using `CUBE` functions within your source table to interrogate the Data Model, thus removing the need for a physical Pivot Table?

Comment: I haven't got any experience with CUBE functions but from my research it seems like it will harm performance. To convert my current set-up would require 10,000's of CUBE functions, each of which is an individual query to the data model.
Currently the Power Pivot table updates in only a few seconds.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using Power Pivot to return data to your main table as opposed to formulas?

Comment: As I said above, it's to avoid a large amount of cube functions which would require more processing than a single pivot table.
The purpose for me using Power Pivot is to utilise the relationship function as it is much more efficient than VLOOKUPs.